# CURL скачать картинку base_64

Tags: php, curl

На сайте картинки проставлены через

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA..........
```

Подскажите, как ее скачать через CURL ?
Обычные картинки по ссылке у меня качаются через CURL без проблем. Возможно, нужно к какому-то виду ее привести ?

Comment: Взять значение аттрибута src тега img и это значение залить в файл, будет картинка.

Comment: по всей видимости  вы не поняли вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base64` - Это строковое представление картинки, конкретно картинку скачать нельзя, ибо она текстом представлена, а отображается в виде картинки благодаря браузеру (он видит этот текст и сам создает изображение).

Если у вас нет проблем с получением той строки, которая указана у вас в вопросе, то чтобы получить **конкретно** картинку [тыкаем сюда и смотрим примеры](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

Comment: просто лучший :)